# Как вывести последние данные конкретного пользователя из базы данных mySQL?

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql, node.js, json

Всем привет

В моём проекте есть база данных mySQL и в ней 2 таблицы courses и timetable. У обеих одинаковая структура - колонки id, user_id, course, reg_date в courses и id, user_id, time, reg_date в timetable. Пользователь может быть записан на разные курсы и уроки проходят в разное время. Мне нужно выводить из таблицы последние course, time для конкретного ученика по user_id, сравнивать с user_id из JSONа и в зависимости от этого продолжать код.

Могу вывести последние значения из базы - SELECT course, time FROM courses, timetable ORDER BY courses.id, timetable.id DESC LIMIT 1, а вот сформулировать на SQL вывод последних course, time для конкретного user_id пока не могу.

Благодарен за любые пинки в нужную сторону)

Comment: `... WHERE user_id =  __ ;` ???

Comment: Большое спасибо за наводку